# Handling success and error responses from http.get in angular 2

Tags: javascript, function, http, angular

I am using foursquare api to grab longitude and latitude coordinates for searched venue, function looks like this:

```
getCoordinates(params) {
   this.http.get(URL+params)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
      data => this.coordinates = data,
      err => this.logError(err)
    );
   // return coordinates;
  }
```

I am trying to figure out how to perform specific tasks in case of success or error, so if it is a success case I want to `return coordinates` if not print an error to the console, but not `return coordinates`. I think I more or less got the error bit down, but can't figure success action (commented it out at the moment as it is called in success and error cases)

**EDIT:** seeing how this question can pop up in the future, what would be logic to check for success or failure of a `http.post` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact the subscribe method allows to register callbacks for success and factures. Perhaps arrow functions disturb you a bit:

```
this.http.get(...)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      // Processing for successfull response
    },
    error => {
      // Processing for failures
    }
  );
```

You can only return the observable (for example from a service) but not a result because HTTP requests are asynchronous. Then you can subscribe on it within components for example and set component attributes to be displayed in the view.

Hope it helps you.
Thierry

Comment: "You can only return the observable (for example from a service)" -- you could return an empty array, and then when the data returns from the server you could push values onto that array (i.e., don't change the array reference).  Angular's change detection should notice (e.g., ngFor bindings will have changed), and your component's view should update just fine.  For an error condition, just don't change the array.

Comment: Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fbTh9P7mxXQPeTPpYlaT?p=preview) demonstrating how that would work.

Answer (score 0):

you can chain the `http.get()` with a `then` function, where you can put the success and error callbacks:

```
this.http.get(URL+params).then(function(data){
    // success
}, function(data){
    // error
});
```